# Android ClassNotFoundException after signing

Tags: android, libgdx, classnotfoundexception

I have a LibGDX game and something strange is happening. When I hit Run in Eclipse, it works fine on my phone. However, when I export a signed APK and install it, the app crashes and shows the following:

```
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner/com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner.GameActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner.GameActivity" on path: /data/app/com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner-1.apk
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner.GameActivity" on path: /data/app/com.radioactivewasp.starshiprunner-1.apk
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
07-01 22:22:56.658: E/AndroidRuntime(12432):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you use ProGuard when signing?

Comment: No, I use Eclipse, using the option AndroidTools -> Export Signed Application

Comment: OK, so, is Eclipse set up to use ProGuard during the export process?

Comment: I actually don't know, I use it with default options since I install the SDK. However I have seen a proguard.cfg file inside my Android project...